# UserControl Textbox Always null (call from another UserControl)

Tags: c#, asp.net

First.ascx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


public void View(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string name = txtName.Text;
}
```

Second.ascx

```
<button type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="Button1_click">View</button>


 protected void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    UserControl uc = (UserControl)LoadControl("First.ascx");
    uc.View(sender, e);
 }
```

Why "txtName" always null, if I create a Button on First.ascx it's normal, but if I call function from Second ascx always null value.

Comment: LoadControl will create a new object from the file First.ascx, if you have not initialized the txtName box to have a default value then it will be returned as null in the second page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadcontrol?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: How can I get value of txtName? any solution without using Loadcontrol?

Comment: It depends on what is your workflow, if user goes from first page to second page, then you can pass the value in the postback, or you can store it in a session/cookie variable. Really the right way would depends on things not mentioned here.

Comment: first and second on 1 aspx(form side and button side), so how best way to get value of txtName?

Answer (score 0):

You should look postback. Because every usercontrols page_load run afeter postback. You can catch your text value after postback in page_load.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Catch your value
    }
```

Comment: so I embedded 2 ascx on 1 aspx, First.ascx(form) and Second.ascx(Button) so, how can I get best way to get value of txtName?